# What is a good place to collect lists of applications?

Tags: community

I want to know where I can find lists of applications and where to put them as well. I have some questions here on AU that are lists and I want to move them to one place for easy access for everyone.

Lists are good if they are up to date; and if you are looking for new software lists are the best.

**So has anyone some recommendations on places where lists of applications can belong?**

they aren't allowed on any of the SE sites according to the FAQ.

**Requirements**

I would like to divide my applications lists in games, multimedia, web browsers etc. But I would also like to link to other sites where I can find software. Especially software that isn't in the USC

Comment: Should this be on the main site, rather than meta?

Comment: @fluteflute I think this is a grey area. I wasn't certain it would belong on the main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the Ubuntu wiki? This is exactly the sort of thing it's for.

To start a new page, head over to (for example), http://wiki.ubuntu.com/MyNewGreatPage

This (assuming the page still doesn't exist yet) will give you a create link, and you can begin editing. The rest is up to you really, if you can being creating a useful resource you'll probably find others will help you along in no time :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I would suggest starting your own site to maintain such lists. If you're not interested in learning HTML/CSS or paying for hosting, you could do what I've done with my hobby site and use [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/).

Then you could share the link with interested users via some sort of social media or your Ask Ubuntu profile, explaining that it is what you would personally recommend for those types of applications.

If others create similar list sites that cater to other tastes in software, you could probably link to them from your own page so it's easier for others to find what they're interested in.

**Warning:** Be aware that if you decide to start such a site and initially populate it with content from pre-existing lists here on Ask Ubuntu, you may have to keep in mind the [license](https://askubuntu.com/faq#editing) it is under before publishing anything.*

<sub>*(*It is most likely due to this reason I don't start my own list site...as those who see me in chat would likely point out, I'm infamously paranoid of potential legal issues.)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I find [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net) really helpful when searching for apps. It provides various lists of applications that you can add to and maintain. It isn't maintained like a wiki and isn't Ubuntu-specific, but it is based on user contributions.

Example lists:

- [Browser category (cross-platform, includes browser extensions)](http://alternativeto.net/category/browsers/)

  - [Browser tag (cross-platform, browsers only)](http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?profile=all&search=tag:browser&sort=likes)
- [Games category (Linux only)](http://alternativeto.net/category/games/?profile=linux)
- [Alternatives to Dropbox (Linux only, FLOSS only)](http://alternativeto.net/software/dropbox/?platform=linux&license=opensource)

Personally I find the fact that it isn't Ubuntu-specific useful, because I can ask [What's a free Linux alternative to Visio, even if it isn't open source?](http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-visio/?profile=linux&platform=linux&license=free) And then I post questions here on AU if I run into problems installing or running it :)

Adding and editing on AT is quite easy, and once few of your submissions are manually approved, they are automatically approved. You can read more about AT on their [about page](http://alternativeto.net/About).

Comment: I've been thinking of starting my own site instead on which I just collect a bunch of lists and try to give a clean and easy to use interface. All the interfaces I've seen so far is quite hard to use. And then make the content available to everyone to edit. That would be cool, I just hope it works...

Comment: Your browser list sucks, the fourth one in the list is adblock! How can you browse the web in adblock?

Comment: my bad, it looks like the browser category includes browser extensions - I've updated the description and added a link to the browser tag, which is for browsers only